# Printing out over four letters Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the words in "first_name" that have 4 or more letters.

What I got so far is

```
first_name = ['john', 'robert']

if len(first_name) >= 4
         print(first_name)
```

Comment: Use a loop to iterate over your list. Inside that list use the condition.

Comment: `for name in first_name: if len(name) >= 4: print(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't iterate through all the names in `first_name` (should probably be called `first_names` because it's a list of multiple first names).

You forgot `:` after the `if`

Other than that seems good.

Working solution:

```
first_names = ['john', 'robert']
for first_name in first_names:
    if len(first_name) >= 4:
        print(first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a loop to iterate through words in `first_name`. While iterating, check the length. Print word if the length constraint is satisfied.

This is one list comprehension way:

```
>>> first_name = ['john', 'robert']
>>> ' '.join([word for word in first_name if len(word) >= 4])
john robert
```